# rbenv install --list not showing all versions on ubuntu 18.04 LTS (ruby 2.7.1)

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rbenv, ruby-build

In the attempt to install ruby 2.7.1 using rbenv I noticed the version was not listed on my ubuntu 18.04

```
$ rbenv install -l | grep 2.7.
  2.7.0-dev
  2.7.0-preview1
  jruby-9.2.7.0
  rbx-2.71828182
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So I found this great resource: [here](https://makandracards.com/makandra/25477-rbenv-how-to-update-list-of-available-ruby-versions-on-linux)

> On Linux, you probably installed ruby-build as an rbenv plugin. Updating is easy:

I checked if ruby-build was installed with

```
$ ruby-build --version
ruby-build 20190615-7-g0e9094b
```

I checked if ruby-build was associated with rbenv checking the installation path:

```
$ which ruby-build 
/home/[username]/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin/ruby-build
```

> `git -C ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build pull`

as suggested in the resource this solved the problem for me.

---

I also noticed as I tried to install an inexistent version that the command gives the same suggestion

```
$ rbenv install 2.7.7
ruby-build: definition not found: 2.7.7

See all available versions with `rbenv install --list'.

If the version you need is missing, try upgrading ruby-build:

  git -C /home/[your_user]/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build pull
```

Answer (score 1):

As [Chilianu Bogdan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3523538/chilianu-bogdan) mentioned, `rbenv` does not manage version by itself, its done via `ruby-build`. If you have it as a plugin, `git -C "$(rbenv root)"/plugins/ruby-build pull` should indeed work.

In case you don't have `plugins/ruby-build` directory, most probably `ruby-build` is installed as standalone app, and you need to upgrade it via package manager or source pull & reinstall